# Give permissions for packages downloaded from the internet and lock them in Ubuntu 12.04 sidebar

Tags: 12.04, permissions, sudo, netbeans

I downloaded NetBeans IDE and Eclipse IDE from the internet and installed then. Well, the Eclipse IDE works fine, but when I execute NetBeans IDE directly from the shortcut, without sudo permission, it shows me lots of error telling that some files are read only. This does not happens when I'm using the terminal to call the .sh script with sudo permissions.

Another thing that bothers me: How can I fix my shortcuts in the Ubuntu's 12.04 sidebar?

I want to combine a launcher with enough permissions to do everything it's needing and fix it in my sidebar. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by the link?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant "shortcut" hehe. I just edited the description.